# '"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2012, nodes, updates

I updated Node.js earlier bc a project I was working on wasn't working correctly so thought maybe I needed to update. The second I updated to node.js 19 everything went to crap. I cant do anything in VSC right now. Cant even create a react app.

I read something about going into the control panel and adding the path for nodejs. Tried that, restarted the computer, and nada.

Help me as I am very sad right now =(

'"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hi could you copy and paste your whole "variable-path"? Sometimes the culprit is the ";" seperator and also could you try and type `node -v` into both powershell and CMD and if you're using WSL1/2? If you never heard of WSL then the chances are that you don't have it enabled which is fine.